# htaccess tidy up url

Tags: php, .htaccess

So I have been trying to get my url to look better, but I can not get it to work as I want, so there might be some nice soul here that can help me out.

I need help with

ex: www.domain.com/project/index.php?p=settings&u=123&l=k

To look like www.domain.com/project/settings

I want index.php to be removed and all that comes after the first variable, in this case, p=settings, and also remove ?p=

I got this now

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl.

```
RewriteRule ^project/([^/]*)$ /project/index.php?p=$1&u=123&l=k [L, QSA]
```

Comment: But that dose only work if the u variable=123 and l variabele = k Those variables are just example, is there a way to just remove what ever come there? Cause I got a bunch of other variables more.

Or could I just put a wildcard * after $1 ?

Answer (score 0):

There is the Possibility to redirect errorcodes

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

In this way you can ask for `www.domain.com/project/settings` witch does not exist and instead of the error 404 you get redirected to /index.php

```
$uri_asked = explode("/", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

then you have

```
$uri_asked[3]="project";
$uri_asked[4]="settings";
```

and you can build something like

```
include("www.domain.com/index.php?p=".$uri_asked[3]."&u=".$uri_asked[4]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule to discard unwanted query string:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?p=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1%1? [R=301,NE,L]
```